# OrientDB ETL Throws exception on loading CSV file

Tags: csv, etl, orientdb

I am trying to load a simple CSV file to OrientDB and it always throws this exception.

CSV File Content

```
id, name, role
1, Sarath, Architect
2, Anoop, Project Manager
3, Nazeem, Lead Developer
4, Rini, Senior Developer
5, Shine, iOS Developer
6, Vishnu, iOS Developer
```

json config file

```
{
  "source": { "file": { "path": "./dev.csv" } },
  "extractor": { "row": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { 
      "csv": {}
    },
    { "vertex": { "class": "Person" } }
  ],

  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "remote:localhost/dev",
       "dbType": "graph",
       "dbUser": "root",
       "dbPassword": "root",
       "dbAutoCreate": true,
       "classes": [
         {"name": "Person", "extends": "V"}
       ], "indexes": [
         {"class":"Person", "fields":["id:integer"], "type":"UNIQUE" }
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

All the time it shows this exception. I tried different CSV options but it did not work. Looks like the file reading itself throwing exception.

```
» oetl posts.json                                                                        sarat@Saraths-MacBook-Air
OrientDB etl v.2.0.1 (build @BUILD@) www.orientechnologies.com
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on loading config file: posts.json
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:151)
```

Platform Details

```
OS X 10.10.2
java version "1.8.0_25"
OrientDB - v.2.0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace gives you the cause of the problem (you only showed the first, not interesting lines in your example).

Check:

- The server is running (you specified `remote:localhost/dev`, so the server must be running on the default port at the same machine).
- The database exists and has "root" / "root" as credentials (note that mostly "admin" "admin" is used)
- The file `dev.csv` is present in the current directory

Tried out your example and works without modification.

Comment: I fixed it by specifying full path for JSON file 'oetl <full path>'. Looks like I need to set ORIENTDB_HOME to work without that.

Comment: mmm, strange. If I unset ORIENTDB_HOME it still works. What was the exact error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it was due to one of the directories in the path to the JSON config file having a space in it. The `oetl` script doesn't handle this well and thus can't find the script.

@rmuller: The OP showed the entire traceback. That's all you get in this case.